# Print specific line and if it contains space - replace or print path

Tags: bash, awk, find

Like in the title - I need to find and read through all files with specific name, check 7th line for specific pattern and if found - print path or replace the line.
I have problem with pipe or exec output of awk.
`find . -name "meta" -exec awk 'NR==7 && /T/' {} \;`

How to pipe output of this command, or use -exec on it?

Comment: `print path or replace the line`? which action do you want to achieve? and what is the pattern to search?

Comment: pattern - `/T/' - line contains T inside. I want to print path of file from which this line was printed OR replace this line in file.

Comment: It may be `01 Jan 1970`, it's not important what pattern to replace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the Awk script to print the file name.

```
find ... -exec awk 'NR==7 && /T/ { print FILENAME }' {} \;
```

or alternatively use an exit code to signal the result back to `find`

```
find ... -exec awk 'NR==7 { exit($0~/T/) }' () \; -o -ls
```

You need to take care to have the same exit code if the file is too short; that's why I use a slightly counter-intuitive nonzero (failure) exit code for the case when a match was found.

If you want to replace the line with the match, `sed -i` might be both easier and more portable, though GNU Awk also has an `--inline` option.

```
find ... -exec sed -i '7s/.*T.*/foobar/' {} \;
```

Notice that you need `sed -i '' '7s...` on *BSD platforms, including OSX (i.e. the `-i` option requires a mandatory option argument; pass it an empty string to not back up files).